# How to select a file and save it in another place in objective c,ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save a pdf file into another folder with objective c in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088785/how-to-save-a-pdf-file-into-another-folder-with-objective-c-in-ios)

How to select the .pdf file locally when a button is tapped.And how to save it in another place in iphone application using objective c.Please help me out with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You simply should read Apple's documentation regarding [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)